# How to create new scheduler task programmatically on Windows machines

Tags: c#, scheduler

Looking for a library I can use with C# to create scheduled task programmatically on Windows machines.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [ask] good question. You need to provide [mcve] what you have tried

Comment: schtasks.exe /?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty broad.

If you have access to the command line you can do this : https://www.howtogeek.com/51236/how-to-create-modify-and-delete-scheduled-tasks-from-the-command-line/

> Create ‘My Task’ to run C:RunMe.bat at 9 AM everyday:

```
SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "My Task" /TR "C:\RunMe.bat" /ST 09:00
```

The documentation of SchTasks can be found here : https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc725744(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Adding link to the answer is potentially broken.